# How memory is allocated when we use malloc to create 2-dimensional array?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, allocation

I want to create an integer `array[5][10]` using `malloc()`. The difference between memory address of `array[0]` and `array[1]` is showing `8`. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int *b[5];

    for (int loop = 0; loop < 5; loop++)
        b[loop] = (int*)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));

    printf("b=%u  \n", b);
    printf("(b+1)=%u \n", (b + 1));
    printf("(b+2)=%u \n", (b + 2));
}
```

The output is:

```
b=2151122304
(b+1)=2151122312 
(b+2)=2151122320
```

Comment: Use `%p` to print address of a variable.

Comment: That's an array of pointers that point to the first elements of arrays.  All the arrays involved are 1D arrays.  The address of `b[1]` is greater than that of `b[0]` by the size of an `int *`, not the size of a 10-element `int` array.  Actual 2D arrays work differently.

Comment: `int (*b)[10] = malloc(5 * 10 * sizeof(int));` would give you a dynamically allocated 2D array of `int` (5 x 10), pointed at by a pointer to 10-element arrays of `int`.

Comment: `int *b[5]` is not a 2D array and cannot point to one. You need a pointer to array, not an array of pointers. There are already tons of questions/answers covering how to allocate multidimensional array. Just ignore those using something like `int **` (which is also no 2D array).

Comment: And your `printf` invokes undefined behaviour. Your compiler should warn, if not enable warnings, if still not, get a modern compiler. `$u` is plain wrong format specifier to print a pointer. Read the `printf` documentation!

Answer (score 4):

> The difference between memory address of array[0] and array[1] is showing 8. Why?

That's because `sizeof` of a pointer on your platform is `8`.

BTW, use of `%u` to print a pointer leads to undefined behavior. Use `%p` instead.

```
printf("(b+1)=%p \n",(b+1));
printf("(b+2)=%p \n",(b+2));
```

**Difference between array of pointers and a 2D array**

When you use:

```
int *b[5];
```

The memory used for `b` is:

```
&b[0]     &b[1]    &b[2]
 |        |        |
 v        v        v
 +--------+--------+--------+
 |  b[0]  |  b[1]  |  b[2]  |
 +--------+--------+--------+
```

`(b+1)` is the same as `&b[1]`
`(b+2)` is the same as `&b[2]`

Hence, the difference between `(b+2)` and `(b+1)` is the size of a pointer.

When you use:

```
int b[5][10];
```

The memory used for `b` is:

```
&b[0][0]                                          &b[1][0]                                          &b[2][0]
|                                                 |                                                 |
v                                                 v                                                 v
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+ ...
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ...
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+ ...
```

`(b+1)` is the same as `&b[1]`, The value of that pointer is the same as the value of `&b[1][0]` even though they are pointers to different types.
`(b+2)` is the same as `&b[2]`, The value of that pointer is the same as the value of `&b[2][0]`

Hence, the difference between `(b+2)` and `(b+1)` is the size of `10` `int`s.

Comment: That makes sense @R_Sahu

Comment: @ShubhamVerma, see the updated answer to understand the difference an array of pointers and a 2D array.

Answer (score 2):

First, with  `int *b[5]` you are not creating a two dimensional array, but an array of pointers.

The elements of the array `b`  are pointers. Each occupies the size of a pointer, which depends on your architecture. In a 64-bits architecture it will probably occupy 64 bits (8 bytes). You can check that by printing `sizeof(int*)` or `sizeof(b[0])`

Answer (score 2):

Memory allocation will look like

```
   b
+-----+
|     |                +------+------+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| b[0]+--------------> |      |      |           |     |     |     |     |
|     |                +------+------+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
+-----+
|     |                +------+------+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| b[1]+--------------> |      |      |.......    |     |     |     |     |
|     |                +------+------+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
+-----+
|     |                +------+------+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| b[2]+--------------> |      |      | ......    |     |     |     |     | 
|     |                +------+------+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
+-----+
|     |                +------+------+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| b[3]+--------------> |      |      | ......    |     |     |     |     |
|     |                +------+------+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
+-----+
|     |                +------+------+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| b[4]+--------------> |      |      | ......    |     |     |     |     |
|     |                +------+------+-----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
+-----+
```

`b` will point to `b[0]`, after decay, and `b + 1` will give the address of `b[1]`. Size of pointer on your machine is 8 bytes, therefore you are getting a difference of 8 in the address.

Beside of this

1. Do not cast return value of `malloc`

   ```
   b[loop]=malloc(10*sizeof(int));
   ```
2. and use `%p` for pointer data type

   ```
   printf("b=%p  \n",(void *)b);
   printf("(b+1)=%p \n",(void *)(b+1));
   printf("(b+2)=%p \n",(void *)(b+2));
   ```

Answer (score 1):

What you've declared is not technically a two dimensional array but an array of pointers to `int`, each of which points to an array of `int`.  The reason `array[0]` and `array[1]` are 8 bytes apart is because you have an array of pointers, and pointers on your system are 8 bytes.

When you allocate each individual 1 dimensional array, they don't necessarily exist next to each other in memory.  If on the other hand you declared `int b[5][10]`, you would have 10 * 5 = 50 contiguous integers arranged in 5 rows of 10.

Comment: What do you mean with "techically"? In what aspect would that be a 2D array?

Comment: @Olaf I mean that once each element in the array points to a dynamically allocated you can generally treat it as a two dimensional array.  As long as you stick with array subscripting, i.e. `b[2][3]` (or equivalently `*(*(b+2)+3)`), instead of doing the math you could on a real 2D array, i.e. `*(b + 2*5 + 3)` you're fine.

Comment: Well, no, you can't. For instance you cannot just `memcpy` it. Or `free` it with a single call. etc. If OP wants a 2D array, he should just use one. There really is no need to fiddle around with jagged arrays or 1D arrays as your comment implies (`*(b + 2*5 + 3)`). That also is no 2D array.